# google-play-services_lib could not be found when migrating to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse

i found this error when i import my eclipse project to android studio

```
App_dijkstra:C:\Users\admin1\Downloads\App_dijkstra\App_dijkstra\project.properties:
Library reference ..\google-play-services_lib could not be found
Path is C:\Users\admin1\Downloads\App_dijkstra\App_dijkstra\..\google-play-services_lib which resolves to C:\Users\admin1\Downloads\App_dijkstra\google-play-services_lib   . . . .  ) -->
```

i have error  with google-play-services

Answer (score 0):

This project uses google-play-services library. you need to upgrade sdk in android studio. In menu bar select Tools < Android < SDK Manager. In sdk manager select google-play-services & update. Its better if you can upgrade all sdk if they are outdated or not installed. Then clean your project and rebuild it. To do that Select Build in menu bar and click clean project, After it finished, click Rebuild project. I hope this will work.